# Unable to locate an href element with an active child span Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have several html elements in my AUT which are in the format shown below:

```
<a href="#home">HOME<span class="activeChild">&nbsp;&gt; Payments</span></a>
```

where the span child element keeps changing depending upon currently active page.

As evident, there is no proper unique locator to use from Selenium WebDriver. Only way I could end up with is building xpath either using link text or using href.

`"//a[(@href='#home')]"` does not work, despite it being unique in the page.

Can anyone please help me locate this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this xpath :- `//a[starts-with(@href, "#home")]` or  `//a[starts-with(text(), "Home")]`

Comment: Thank you Ankur. This seems to have worked. I will play around a bit. Thanks again.